# Getting BeanCreationException in context.xml when using spring 4.3.15 version

Tags: spring

I am getting BeanCreationException while creating bean for ClassUtils in context.xml

Error Details:

> Caused by:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;

Bean created using Spring 3.2.18 in context.xml

```
<bean id="id1" class="org.spring.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
 <property name="targetClass"><value>org.springframework.util.ClassUtils</value>
<property name="targetMethod"><value>forName</value></property>
 </property>
 <property name="arguments">
  <list><value>MyClassName</value></list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

But in spring 4.3.15 the method forName has changed in terms parameter passing 
Now it is expecting forName(String name,ClassLoader loader) in ClassUtils class.
I am not sure how to pass ClassLoader to this method by passing as argument using above context.xml.

Comment: Why this contraption to construct a bean instance? What is wrong with just a bean definition with a `class` attribute? The end result would be the same.

Comment: Thanks Deinum for the info. We are following this standards for the instance creation. We need to pass class loader as argument  through this xml for the method forName in ClassUtils class. Please suggest if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that... It is complex, error prone and adds nothing but complexity and overhead. `<bean id="id1" class="MyClassName" />` yields exactly the same result without the mess of using the factory bean. Basically you are doing tings you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

Comment: Let me try that by using your suggestion. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks Deinum for the info, I have followed your steps, but unfortunately it didnt work. May be some other config is missing. I have added <null/> below the <value> section. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Still it is overly complex and only adds complexity to your setup. You should be fixing the related error as what you are doing is something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Sure Deinum, in my project they are following old configs I guess. I will remove those and create latest one as per your suggestion. Thanks again.